# Typescript Decorator on method; get method in decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I am trying to make a decorator that can:

1. Take a parameter
2. Store the method it is above as a callable function
3. Map the callable function with the parameter the decorator takes.

Here is what I tried:

```
class Foo {

    static cachedMethods: Map<string, (arg: string) => void> = new Map();

    static decorator = (decoratorArg: string) => (
        target: Object, 
        propertyKey: string,
        descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>
        ): any => Foo.cachedMethods.set(decoratorArg, target as (arg: string) => void);

}

class Bar {
   @Foo.decorator("some data")
   method1(arg: string) {
      console.log(arg);
   }

   @Foo.decorator("some other data")
   method2(arg: string) {
       console.log(arg);
   }
}

let func: Function = Foo.cachedMethods.get("some data")!;
func("hello world");
```

However, it says that func is not a function. It is storing it as the Bar class. How can I store the method as a function?

Answer (score 1):

The `target` 1st argument that is received by the decorator function is actually the class prototype. So in your case it will be `Bar` prototype.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators

> The expression for the method decorator will be called as a function at runtime, with the following three arguments:
>
> 1. Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member.
> 2. The name of the member.
> 3. The Property Descriptor for the member.

Since you want to store a reference to the *method*, you can use `target[propertyKey]` or `descriptor.value`

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)